# how can I convert my data-frame into a list with the values as strings, rather than as a list of lists

Tags: pandas, dataframe

My csv file is local and conatins information that I cannot link up here

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
ports = pd.read_csv("Airportimp_data.csv")
flights = pd.read_csv("airportroutes.csv")
c = pd.DataFrame(flights,columns = ['fromm'])
qwe = c.values.tolist()
print(qwe)
```

This is how a sample of my list looks

```
[['SKP'], ['SKP'], ['SKP'], ['SKP'], ['SKP'], ['SKP'], ['SKP'], ['SKP'], ['SKP'], ['SKP'], ['SKP'], ['SKP'], ['SOF'], ['SOF'], ['SOF'], ['SOF'], ['SOF'], ['SOF'], ['SOF'], ['SOF'], ['SOF'], ['SOF'], ['SOF'], ['SOF'], ['SOF'], ['SOF'], ['SZZ'], ['SZZ'], ['TLV'], ['TRF'], ['TRF'], ['TRF'], ['TRF'], ['TRF'], ['TRF'], ['TRF'], ['TRF'], ['TRF'], ['TSR'], ['TSR']]
```

As you can see it is a list of lists which I want to convert each element into a a string with out the square brackets

Comment: `str(c.tolist())` ? can you add a sample of your data if possible.

Comment: @Datanovice I've added a part of the list

Comment: I think your problem is your calling `tolist` after `values` use `c.tolist()`  or if you really want to unpack the values then `[inner_item for item in qwe for inner_item in item]` but your creating the nested list by calling a list on a numpy array

Answer (score 0):

I think that what you want is something like this:

```
lists = [['SKP'], ['SKP'], ['SKP']]
[l[0] for l in lists]
```

Output:

```
['SKP', 'SKP', 'SKP']
```

You can also use map:

```
list(map(lambda x : x[0], lists))
```

Comment: Did this solution fix your problem @user13714027?